# How to create composite figures in draw2d.js

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I've looked through the collection of examples, that go with the library, but unfortunatelly, all examples, devoted to composite figures, are based on parsing json file.

```
reader.unmarshal(canvas, jsonDocument);
```

However, what I want to see is how to create composite figures from basic ones, something like:

```
var figure_1 = new draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle(....);
var figure_1 = new draw2d.shape.basic.Diamond(....);
... then do something, so that figure_1 and figure_2 are now part of
... a composite figure
```

PS. I think what I need is [StrongComposite](http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_5/#!/api/draw2d.shape.composite.StrongComposite), but I do not know how to use it. Hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

This is what I tried:

```
var baseRectangle =  new draw2d.shape.composite.StrongComposite({width: 200, height: 200, x: conf.x, y: conf.y});
var top = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({width: 120, height: 40, x: conf.x, y: conf.y});
var bottom = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({width: 120, height: 40, x: conf.x, y: conf.y + 60});
baseRectangle.assignFigure(top);
baseRectangle.assignFigure(bottom);
canvas.add(baseRectangle);
```

But it does not work. I only see a gray box. I also tried this:

```
var baseRectangle =  new draw2d.shape.composite.StrongComposite({width: 200, height: 200, x: conf.x, y: conf.y});
var top = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({width: 120, height: 40, x: conf.x, y: conf.y});
var bottom = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({width: 120, height: 40, x: conf.x, y: conf.y + 60});
baseRectangle.assignFigure(top);
baseRectangle.assignFigure(bottom);
canvas.add(top);
canvas.add(bottom);
```

But as a result, I got absolutely independent ovals.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add `baseRectangle` to canvas.

```
var baseRectangle = new draw2d.shape.composite.StrongComposite({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    x: conf.x,
    y: conf.y
});
canvas.add(baseRectangle);

var top = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
    x: conf.x,
    y: conf.y
});
var bottom = new draw2d.shape.basic.Oval({
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
    x: conf.x,
    y: conf.y + 60
});

baseRectangle.assignFigure(top);
baseRectangle.assignFigure(bottom);

canvas.add(top);
canvas.add(bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to needing to put the child elements on the canvas (sorry, can't comment on existing answer yet): I found I need to wait a frame (`nextTick` with Vue) before `assignFigure` can work. Otherwise draw2d throws exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'paper')
    at Class.createShapeElement (null:23614:34)
    at Class.getShapeElement (null:8492:33)
    at Class.toFront (null:8351:22)
    at Class.toFront
```